# What loss functions are associated with the distributions in h2o xgboost and gbm?

Tags: h2o, loss-function

I need to know which loss functions are used in the h2o gbm and xgboost functions for the gaussian, binomial and multinomial distributions. Unfortunately, my knowledge of Java is very limited and I can't really decipher the source code, and there doesn't seem to be any document clarifying which distribution is associated with which function. I think I gather from [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/DistributionFactory.java) that it's logloss for binomial and MSE for gaussian, but I can't find anything for multinomial. Does anybody here maybe know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your question. We definitely should provide this information in the [documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/distribution.html). We are working on improving the doc. To answer your question:

The loss function for multinomial classification is softmax for H2O GBM and XGBoost too. H2O GBM is implemented based on this [paper](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ejhf/ftp/trebst.pdf): Greedy function approximation: A gradient boosting machine, Jerome H. Friedman 2001. In chapter 4.6. the author nicely explains how it is calculated and why.

[image]

Based on loss function the `negHalfGradient` method is defined and every distribution implements it individually. For multinomial distribution ([here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/e9a0f7b8aab25cad38454c4d109f74540e9435a3/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/DistributionFactory.java#L269)) the implementation is:

```
@Override
public double negHalfGradient(double y, double f, int l) {
    return ((int) y == l ? 1f : 0f) - f;
}
```

Where:

- `y` is an actual response
- `f` is a predicted response in link space
- `l` is a class label (converted lexicographically from original labels to 0-number of class - 1)

Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. Just one follow-up question: Was I right in assuming that MSE is used for gaussian and logloss for binomial? Are there any differences between XGBoost and GBM in terms of the loss functions?